# How to solve pkg_resources.VersionConflict error during bin/python bootstrap.py -d

Tags: python, setuptools, buildout

I am tring to create a new plone environment using python plone-devstart.py tool. I got a bootstrap error. So i used a command bin/python bootstrap.py -d from my project directory. It(bin/python bootstrap.py -d command) worked fine before But now i got an error like

```
oomsys@oomsysmob-6:~/demobrun$ bin/python bootstrap.py -d
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-  
0.6.49.tar.gz
Extracting in /tmp/tmpDqVwYA
Now working in /tmp/tmpDqVwYA/distribute-0.6.49
Building a Distribute egg in /tmp/tmpv4Bzyv
/tmp/tmpv4Bzyv/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bootstrap.py", line 118, in <module>
ws.require('zc.buildout' + VERSION)
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in require
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 600, in resolve
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 0.6c11 (/home/oomsys/demobrun  
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg),    
Requirement.parse('setuptools>=0.7'))
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have the `distribute` fork of `setuptools` installed in your site packages, but your `bootstrap.py` is trying to install `buildout` 2.2.0, which uses the new *merged* `setuptools` 0.7 or newer egg.

The `distribute` fork of `setuptools` was merged back into the `setuptools` project and the transition is causing some pain.

Your options are:

#### Tell `bootstrap` to use an earlier `zc.buildout` version

Run `bootstrap.py` with the `-v` option, forcing it to stick to a specific, earlier version:

```
 $ bin/python bootstrap.py -d -v 2.1.1
```

Version 2.1.1 of buildout will not upgrade itself to 2.2 or newer and works with your `distribute`-supplied `setuptools` egg.

#### Uninstall the old `distribute` egg

Manually delete all `distribute*`, `pkg_resources.py*` and `setuptools*` files from your `site-packages` directory:

```
$ rm -rf /home/oomsys/demobrun/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools*
$ rm -rf /home/oomsys/demobrun/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute*
$ rm -rf /home/oomsys/demobrun/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py*
```

and (optionally) reinstall `setuptools` from with the latest `ez_setup.py`; the current version is 0.9.6, and the [`setuptools` PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.6) links you to [this `ez_setup.py` version](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/downloads/ez_setup.py).

You'll also need to upgrade your `bootstrap.py` script, see below.

#### Use a recent `virtualenv`

Version 1.9 or newer of `virtualenv` (released March 2013) lets you create a virtualenv without the `setuptools` egg using the `--no-setuptools` switch:

```
$ virtualenv --no-setuptools buildout_env
```

Use that to create a virtual env python to run your `bootstrap.py`. You still need to upgrade your `bootstrap.py` too. See below.

#### Upgrade your `bootstrap.py`.

For `zc.buildout` versions 2.2.0 and up the `bootstrap.py` script has been updated to load `setuptools` the-not-forked-version. Grab a new copy at [from github (link to the 2 branch version)](https://raw.github.com/buildout/buildout/2/bootstrap/bootstrap.py), replace your old `bootstrap.py` with it, and bootstrap again.

Do make sure you removed the old forked really-`distribute`-but-pretending-to-be-`setuptools` egg first or run with a virtual env python that does not have that egg. See above.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. What is your recommended option going forward?

Comment: I've uninstalled `distribute` and use the newer `setuptools` everywhere, but I am currently in a position with almost no legacy projects (older code). Your situation may differ.

Answer (score 60):

You could also try:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

as documented here https://askubuntu.com/questions/318824/how-to-solve-pkg-resources-versionconflict-error-during-bin-python-bootstrap-py/322701#322701

Comment: this did the trick for me, and was much faster then the suggestions above... needed a sudo in my case

Comment: This worked for me but did not need `sudo` as I was operating in a virtualenv.

Comment: error for me: `File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 536
    {str(c.version) for c in all_candidates},
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax