# DistributionNotFound error when trying to bootstrap

Tags: python, setuptools, buildout

I'm trying to use `zc.buildout` and bootstrap it. But during bootstrap I'm getting error:

```
cleg$ /usr/local/bin/python bootstrap.py
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.49.tar.gz
Extracting in /var/folders/ky/t76hxgx529s642rfd8vywd280000gn/T/tmpAXsdCh
Now working in /var/folders/ky/t76hxgx529s642rfd8vywd280000gn/T/tmpAXsdCh/distribute-0.6.49
Building a Distribute egg in /var/folders/ky/t76hxgx529s642rfd8vywd280000gn/T/tmpQuAu95
/var/folders/ky/t76hxgx529s642rfd8vywd280000gn/T/tmpQuAu95/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 253, in <module>
    ws.require(requirement)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in require
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 596, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: setuptools>=0.7
```

I've tried to isolate project from system, and used Virtualenv to create "clean" python, but got the same error.

I've tried to update setuptools with pip, and in `site-packages` folder I've got `setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg`, but looks like bootstrap doesn't see it.

I'm using python 2.7.5 built with homebrew. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: The exception differs a little, but the underlying problems are the same; your `bootstrap.py` needs updating to switch back to `setuptools` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for pointing me for possible answer, I'll try it and if it's OK — will close question.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the bootstrap file from this URL :
http://downloads.buildout.org/2/bootstrap.py

Maybe you also have to follow the instructions from this question:
[How to solve pkg_resources.VersionConflict error during bin/python bootstrap.py -d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586987/how-to-solve-pkg-resources-versionconflict-error-during-bin-python-bootstrap-py)

Comment: Which is why I voted to close the question as a dupe. Note that my answer *includes* instructions on upgrading the bootstrap script, but that may *not* be enough.