# Zope bootstrap setuptools error

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, zope, buildout

I've done many zope/plone related projects and many bootstraps and buildouts. Since yesterday I get an error on every bootstrap I try to run. Nothing has changed on my system. I don't have any clue what could be wrong. Here's the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 258, in <module>
    ws.require(requirement)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 569, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 0.6c12dev-r88846 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=0.7'))
```

I started with python coding some days ago since I know several other languages but not python. Seems like this has something to do with the version of setuptools. Sadly I don't know how to update it or pin it to a specific version.

Or is it something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve pkg\_resources.VersionConflict error during bin/python bootstrap.py -d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586987/how-to-solve-pkg-resources-versionconflict-error-during-bin-python-bootstrap-py)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Python easy\_install not working on my Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012246/why-is-python-easy-install-not-working-on-my-mac)

Answer (score 0):

The version of setuptools you are using is 0.6

try upgrading it and everything will be fine.

For package you are installing the version of setuptools should be >=0.7

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```