# Setuptools Version Conflict Error when building Python Project

Tags: python, setuptools

I am attempting to build a python project and I am running into a Version Conflict error with setuptools.  I receive the following error message:

```
An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1942, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 463, in install
    self._load_extensions()
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 998, in _load_extensions
    ep.load()(self)
  File "/Users/raul/PhpstormProjects/clients/ceres/test/ceres/eggs/buildout.eggtractor-0.6-py2.6.egg/buildout/eggtractor/tractor.py", line 68, in install
    part_names = [n for n in buildout['buildout']['tractor-target-parts'].split() if n in buildout]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 105, in __contains__
    return self.has_key(key)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 100, in has_key
    value = self[key]
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1094, in __getitem__
    options._initialize()
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1198, in _initialize
    self.initialize()
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1204, in initialize
    recipe_class = _install_and_load(reqs, 'zc.buildout', entry, buildout)
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1158, in _install_and_load
    allow_hosts=buildout._allow_hosts
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 812, in install
    return installer.install(specs, working_set)
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 653, in install
    self._maybe_add_setuptools(ws, dist)
  File "/project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 595, in _maybe_add_setuptools
    if ws.find(requirement) is None:
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 515, in find
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req)     # XXX add more info
VersionConflict: (setuptools 0.8 (/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.8-py2.6.egg), Requirement.parse('setuptools==0.6c11'))
```

This error is similar to the one discussed here: [How to solve pkg_resources.VersionConflict error during bin/python bootstrap.py -d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586987/how-to-solve-pkg-resources-versionconflict-error-during-bin-python-bootstrap-py)

The key difference is that my error tells me to downgrade from version 0.8 to 0.6cll, while the error in the linked post requires an upgrade to resolve the error.

Also note the statement: Requirement.parse('setuptools==0.6c11').  This seems to require an exact match and causes an error even though a newer version is installed.

In fact, I have already tried downgrading to version 0.6c11, and I get the following error message:

```
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: setuptools 0.6c11
but distribute 0.7.3 requires 'setuptools>=0.7'.
but zc.buildout 2.2.0 requires 'setuptools>=0.7'.
```

So it appears that Some Thing requires setuptoos==0.6c11 and Another Thing requires setuptools>=0.7.  I'm pretty sure I can't meet both requirements.

I am trying to setup a development environment on a Mac OsX 10.7 and using Python version 2.6 (required by the project).  Any Idea how I can resolve this issue?

Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue and am posting the solution in case someone runs into this same problem.

It turns out that the problem was caused by using the version of python 2.6 that comes with Xcode Dev Tools.  This version of python insisted on setuptools version 0.6c11.  Since something else in the application I was installing (Plone CMS) required a version of setuptools>=0.7, I could not use this Mac provided version of Python.

Instead, I installed an alternate version of python 2.6 from source (available here: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.7/).  I used the newly installed version of python and was able to successfully run the bootstrap.py script.